# Chaining promises with multiple arguments

Tags: javascript, promise

I have just started using promises in Javascript and I'm wondering if there is a way to reduce the boilerplate code of wrapping every `then` callback in a function? I find myself doing this a lot and wondering if there is a better way

For example in my `getSettings` function below it either returns a settings model from the database (`then`) or a default settings model (`catch`).

```
var getSettings = function(instance, id, mode) {
    return findByInstance(instance)
        .then(function(data) {
            return useModelFromData(data, id, mode);
        })
        .catch(function() {
            return useDefaultModel(id, mode)
        });
};

var useModelFromData = function(data, id, mode) {
    var settings = data.model.settings;
    applyFeatures(settings, id, mode);
    return data.model;
};

var useDefaultModel = function(id, mode) {
    var model = myModel.getDefaultModel();
    applyFeatures(model.settings, id, mode);
    return model;
};
```

I know that if the then callback takes a single argument and returns a value you can do the following shortcut:

```
get('some_url').then(JSON.parse).then(function(response) {
  console.log("response", response);
});
```

Is there any shortcut I can do for multiple arguments?

Comment: spread works if you return an array of arguments - see the bluebird api for spread: https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#spreadfunction-fulfilledhandler--function-rejectedhandler----promise

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) and move the argument list around

```
var getSettings = function(instance, id, mode) {
    return findByInstance(instance)
        .then(useModelFromData.bind(null, id, mode))
        .catch(useDefaultModel.bind(null, id, mode));
};

var useModelFromData = function(id, mode, data) {
    var settings = data.model.settings;
    applyFeatures(settings, id, mode);
    return data.model;
};

var useDefaultModel = function(id, mode) {
    var model = myModel.getDefaultModel();
    applyFeatures(model.settings, id, mode);
    return model;
};
```

With bind you can set arguments to be prepended to the arguments list when the function is executed. So in this case `id` and `mode` will get prepended to the arguments that get passed to `useModelFromData` and `useDefaultModel`

Comment: This is a good idea, but only really works if this case because id and mode are in scope already.  If findByInstance returned three other variables, you would have to find another way.  It is an excellent solution for the code snippet that the op posted.

Comment: @rquinn: a Promise can only pass one variable onto the next function, though people often use arrays to work around this.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy - Yes, but .spread effectively passes multiple variables to the next function.  You have to return an array, but the function that accepts multiple arguments behaves no differently.

Comment: would there also be a way to do it with currying or does it not make sense to do so?

Answer (score 0):

I went through this today and this is what I came up with....

```
function p(func){
  var args=[];
  for(var i=1,end=arguments.length;i<end;i++)args.push(arguments[i]);
   return function(response){
     for(var i=0,end=args.length;i<end;i++){
       if(args[i]=='{response}')args[i]=response;
     }
    return func.apply(func,args);
   }
}
```

With p you wouldnt have needed to change the arguments of the functions your calling, you could have just done....

```
var getSettings = function(instance, id, mode) {
    return findByInstance(instance)
        .then(p(useModelFromData, '{response}', id, mode))
        .catch(p(useDefaultModel, id, mode));
};
```

Heres the page I came up with it on...
http://plnkr.co/edit/4EGDTk?p=preview
...you might find the other functions useful.